# Convert a Base64 to a Blob Netsuite SuiteScript (Javascript server-side)

Tags: httprequest, blob, multipartform-data, netsuite, suitescript

I have to send, via `https.request`, a PDF file, but I only have the Base64 content and the only format that the server accepts is the byte array.

In JavaScript, on the client side, that's very simple (`UInt8Array` and `Blob`) but those are not implemented in NetSuite so I can't use them. Is there any alternative way to do that without using `UInt8Array` or `Blob`?

I compose the body of the multipart/form-data request and in the body I decoded the Base64 to a UTF-8 string but it doesn't work, it sends the file correctly but is empty.

The format that I need is application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following function to convert to Uint8Array:

```
function stringToUint8Array(input) {
    var out = new Array(input.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        out[i] = input.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return out;
}
```

It might screw up some characters though, I have never tested it for that purpose. I used it for a compression library I reverse engineered to work serverside and it worked.

Comment: Is this just enough for the request? What about the Blob?

Comment: Hi Guys - I know this is very old post but I got stuck with the same issue. Is there a solution with this issue? I also need to create pdf/image files in sharepoint. I can create the files easily but they end up empty(pdf). In postman I can successfully create the file without issues by sending the data as binary. As OP says we only have the base64 content. Thank you in advance!